I want to fitting a Curve for Multiple variable function using python
i have a data frame like this



Area
Room
Parking
Warehouse
Elevator
Address
Price




63
1
True
True
False
Shahran
61666.67


60
1
False
False
False
Shahran
30083.33


79
2
True
False
False
Pardis
20000.00


95
2
False
True
True
Narmak
71666.67


123
2
True
True
True
Zafar
79000.00



and then i change it like this



Area
Room
Parking
Warehouse
Elevator
Address
Price




63
1
1
1
0
1
61666.67


60
1
0
0
0
1
30083.33


79
2
1
0
0
2
20000.00


95
2
0
1
1
3
71666.67


123
2
1
1
1
4
79000.00



my "Area" type was str so i change all data fram type to int64 with this code:
Numeric_HDS = coded_address_HDS.astype("int64")
so i want to fitting a curve to my data

non-linear

multiple linear


for "multiple linear" i think this is the formula:
Y = aX1 + bX2 +cX3 + dX4 + gX5 + hX6
and for "non-linear" i chose:
Y = 1 / 1 + e^beta1(X - beta2)
were X is  aX1 + bX2 +cX3 + dX4 + gX5 + hX6
and my code is like this:
def Multiple_Sigmoid_f(beta1, beta2, theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5, theta6, Numeric_HDS):
    Area,Room,Parking,Warehouse,Elevator,Address \
    = Numeric_HDS[0],Numeric_HDS[1],Numeric_HDS[2],Numeric_HDS[3],Numeric_HDS[4],Numeric_HDS[5]
    X = (theta1*Area) + (theta2*Room) + (theta3*Parking) + (theta4*Warehouse) + (theta5*Elevator) + (theta6*Address)
    Y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(beta1*(X-beta2)))
    return Y

def Multiple_f(theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5, theta6, Numeric_HDS):
    Area,Room,Parking,Warehouse,Elevator,Address \
    = Numeric_HDS[0],Numeric_HDS[1],Numeric_HDS[2],Numeric_HDS[3],Numeric_HDS[4],Numeric_HDS[5]
    Y = (theta1*Area) + (theta2*Room) + (theta3*Parking) + (theta4*Warehouse) + (theta5*Elevator) + (theta6*Address)
    return Y

msk = np.random.rand(len(Numeric_HDS)) < 0.8
train = Numeric_HDS[msk]
test = Numeric_HDS[~msk]

X_train = np.asanyarray(train[["Area","Room","Parking","Warehouse","Elevator","Address"]]).transpose()
Y_real_train = np.asanyarray(train["Price"])

I want to fitting a curve but i get "Index error" when using curve_fit
using python
the exact error traceback is:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[212], line 1
----> 1 CV = curve_fit(Multiple_Sigmoid_f, X_train, Y_real_train)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:963, in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, full_output, nan_policy, **kwargs)
    960 if ydata.size != 1 and n > ydata.size:
    961     raise TypeError(f"The number of func parameters={n} must not"
    962                     f" exceed the number of data points={ydata.size}")
--> 963 res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    964 popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    965 ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:415, in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    413 if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    414     args = (args,)
--> 415 shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    416 m = shape[0]
    418 if n > m:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:25, in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     23 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     24                 output_shape=None):
---> 25     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     26     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     27         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:507, in _lightweight_memoizer.<locals>._memoized_func(params)
    504 if np.all(_memoized_func.last_params == params):
    505     return _memoized_func.last_val
--> 507 val = f(params)
    509 if _memoized_func.last_params is None:
    510     _memoized_func.last_params = np.copy(params)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:523, in _wrap_func.<locals>.func_wrapped(params)
    522 def func_wrapped(params):
--> 523     return func(xdata, *params) - ydata

Cell In[130], line 3, in Multiple_Sigmoid_f(theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5, theta6, Numeric_HDS)
      1 def Multiple_Sigmoid_f(theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5, theta6, Numeric_HDS):
      2     Area,Room,Parking,Warehouse,Elevator,Address \
----> 3     = Numeric_HDS[0],Numeric_HDS[1],Numeric_HDS[2],Numeric_HDS[3],Numeric_HDS[4],Numeric_HDS[5]
      4     Y = (theta1*Area) + (theta2*Room) + (theta3*Parking) + (theta4*Warehouse) + (theta5*Elevator) + (theta6*Address)
      5     return Y

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.


What is your exact error traceback?

You want to regress at least 6 parameters from 5 observations, this makes the problem undetermined. Do you have more data in your dataset?
